# Python : Download CSV file from a URL after login authentication

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests, urllib

I want to download some data as a csv from an Airbnb that requires a login to download. So, I tried:

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
username = "username"
password = "password"
url = 'someurl'
values = { 'username': username,'password': password }
data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values).encode("utf-8")
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url, data)
result = response.read()
print (result)
```

I manage to get the API call URL through right click-> Inspect Element ->Network but I got

`HTTP Error 403: Forbidden`.

I tried using the requests module too:

```
import requests
username = "username"
password = "password"
url = 'someurl'
print(requests.get(url, auth=(username, password)).content)
```

But got an error:

`b'{"error_code":401,"error":"authentication_required","error_message":"Please log in to continue."}'`

Is there any way from which I can extract this data?

Edit: My Airbnb booking history's search query is the required URL here.

Comment: Without the url it might be hard to get an answer.

Comment: My Airbnb booking history's search query is the required URL here. I hope this might help.